# Laravel - Approve and decline buttons on one form for same controller with form action

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel

I have two buttons on my form, `Approve` and `Decline`

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['holidays.update', $holidayRequest->id]]) }} 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
   <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Approve
</button>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
   <i class="fa fa-times"></i>Decline
</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

There is an object called `$holidayRequest` which I have passed to this form from the controller, and my intention is to send a value of the `$holidayRequest->status` back to the controller. That is, one of the following should occur:

1. **User clicks on Approve:** `$holidayRequest->status == 'approved'` is sent to controller.
2. **User clicks on Decline:**  `$holidayRequest->status == 'declined'` is sent to controller.

Should I use the attribute `formaction`to achieve this goal or something else? How do I go about this with as little or no JS as possible?

Comment: Why **little or no JS** ?

Comment: Just JS issues with browsers, that's all

Comment: You have to use JS or Jquery otherwise you have to submit form

Comment: I'm open to all suggestions

Comment: You don't need JS for this, why not keep it simple and just use radio buttons to select approved or declined?

Comment: @AndyHolmes I'd decided to implement two HTML buttons without JS, each with its own action.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this using `jquery()`:

Html:

```
<button type="button" id="approved" class="btn btn-success response">
   <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Approve
</button>

<button type="button" id="declined" class="btn btn-danger response">
   <i class="fa fa-times"></i>Decline
</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.response').click(function(){
    var resposne = $(this).attr('id');
    // It gives you: approved or declined

    // make an ajax call with this response and update the data in database
});
```

**Note:** Do not forget to include jquery library in your page.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want javascript then try submitting them individually.

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['holidays.update', $holidayRequest->id]]) }} 
<input type="hidden" status="approved"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
   <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Approve
</button>
{{ Form::close() }}

{{ Form::open(['route' => ['holidays.update', $holidayRequest->id]]) }} 
<input type="hidden" status="declined"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
   <i class="fa fa-times"></i>Decline
</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```